# MySQL how to assign AUTO_INCREMENT sequence with myisam in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table MySQL MyISAM engine.

```
Primary key column name "id" AUTO_INCREMENT //No sequence assigned!
```

I would like to assign an `AUTO_INCREMENT sequence= "00001"`, so that when I add new rows

I  would get:

```
row  1) id=00001
row  2) id=00002
row  3) id=00003
...............
row  9) id=00009
row 10) id=00010
```

My intent is to keep the value for id of a fix length of 5 characters until 99.999 records.

Is this possible from phpmyadmin? Can I alter my table this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the length of the int-field to be 5 (INT(5)) and select "ZEROFILL" (or specify it as an attribute if you're doing the CREATE/ALTER-statements in SQL).

Any value above 5 digits will be returned as usual (100000), while the smaller values will be prefixed with zeroes (00001).